# Change the visible part of the scrollView

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uiimage

Lets say i have two images (arrows)

```
[leftArrow setFrame:CGRectMake(4, 390, 40, 40)];
[rightArrow setFrame:CGRectMake(276, 390, 40, 40)];
```

and i want to change the scrollView

`scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake`

to some other value. How to do this

the point of this is that i have a scroll view with images and when i slide with mu finger the next image comes but i also want to be able to do this when i press on the Arrow Image (they're not buttons)
so basically change the visible scroll view value when pressing somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you have to use UIScrollView's setContentOffset: function

Comment: something like 
CGPoint bottomOffset = CGPointMake(0, [scrollView contentSize].height);
[scrollView setContentOffset: bottomOffset animated: YES];
??

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain a variable to keep a count you are on which page.

eg. `int scrolls = 0;`

Say you have two methods being called whenever your scrollView is scrolled in forward or backward direction. In those method you can set the rect which is supposed to be visible.

```
-(IBAction)fArrowPressed:(id)sender
    {
        scrolls++;
        [scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(scrollView.frame.size.width*scrolls, 0, scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height) animated:YES];
    }

-(IBAction)bArrowPressed:(id)sender
{
    scrolls--;
    [scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(scrollView.frame.size.width*scrolls, 0, scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height) animated:YES];
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I wasn't clear enough: How to make the scroll view to scroll when i press the part of the screen where the arrow image is? How can this call the action? Can this be done or i have to make the arrow images as buttons

Comment: indeed the arrows will be buttons